# OCI: How to get in terraform OKE prepared images?

Tags: oracle, terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

all

I want to select automatically the image for the node in kubernetes nodepool when I select Shape, Operating System and Version. For this, I have this datasource

```hcl
data "oci_core_images" "images" {
    #Required
    compartment_id = var.cluster_compartment

    #Optional
    # display_name = var.image_display_name
    operating_system = var.cluster_node_image_operating_system
    operating_system_version = var.cluster_node_image_operating_system_version
    shape = var.cluster_node_shape
    state = "AVAILABLE"
    # sort_by = var.image_sort_by
    # sort_order = var.image_sort_order
}
```

and I select the image in `oci_containerengine_node_pool`as

```hcl
resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "node_pool01" {
# ...
    node_shape = var.cluster_node_shape
    node_shape_config {
        memory_in_gbs = "16"
        ocpus = "1"
    }
    node_source_details {
        image_id = data.oci_core_images.images.images[0].id
        source_type = "IMAGE"
    }

}
```

But my problem *seems* to be that not all images are prepared for OKE (with the OKE software install in cloudinit).

So the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Reference/contengimagesshapes.htm) suggest to use the oci cli command:

`oci ce node-pool-options get --node-pool-option-id all`

And my question is: How can I do this in data in terraform (recover only OKE ready images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `oci_containerengine_node_pool_option`

```
data "oci_containerengine_node_pool_option" "test_node_pool_option" {
    #Required
    node_pool_option_id = oci_containerengine_node_pool_option.test_node_pool_option.id

    #Optional
    compartment_id = var.compartment_id
}
```

Ref doc : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/oracle/oci/latest/docs/data-sources/containerengine_node_pool_option

Github issue : https://github.com/oracle-terraform-modules/terraform-oci-oke/issues/263

Change log release details : https://github.com/oracle-terraform-modules/terraform-oci-oke/blob/main/CHANGELOG.adoc#310-april-6-2021